# Spring JavaConfig: Add mapping for custom Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

In a javaconfig-based Spring 4.0 project, how can I add a mapping for a certain URL to a Servlet other than the Spring DispatcherServlet.

Im my case I want to use h2console from H2 database which is provided through the servlet `org.h2.server.web.WebServlet`

**Edit:** In the upcoming Spring Boot 1.3 the h2console can be enabled with a configuration parameter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql-h2-console

Enabling it is as simple as adding these two lines to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
```

Comment: How are you bootstrapping your `DispatcherServlet`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use initializer implementing directly WebApplicationInitializer and the add into `onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)` method following code;

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic h2Servlet = servletContext.addServlet("h2Servlet", new org.h2.server.web.WebServlet());
h2Servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
h2Servlet.addMapping("/h2/*");
```